# Vaadin: Images in Grid with IndexedContainer

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

So I'm trying to add Images to my Grid using an IndexedContainer with the following code:

```
    //picture
    String imgURL = (String)ds.child(PHOTO).getValue();//gets the image URL from the DB
    System.out.println(imgURL);
    ExternalResource picture = new ExternalResource(imgURL);
    System.out.println(picture.getURL());
    Image image = new Image(PICTURE, picture);
    image.setHeight("5px");
    item.getItemProperty(PICTURE).setValue(image);
```

Instead of getting the picture, I'm getting the `toString()` of the Image object. Both `println` print the correct URL. Also note that this works with Table but not with Grid. Any idea why?

Comment: Which println printed the correct URL? What value has PICTURE?

Comment: Both did. This is what is shown in the grid cell: com.vaadin.ui.Image@1e37c05d

Comment: Did the answer help? Please give feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display an image in a Vaadin Grid column, you need to set the ImageRenderer, see [here](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-grid.html#components.grid.renderer) paragraph ImageRenderer.

Example: Define your column like

```
grid.addColumn("picture", Resource.class).setRenderer(new ImageRenderer());
```

then add a resource as column value

```
grid.addRow(new ThemeResource("img/copernicus-128px.jpg"), "Nicolaus Copernicus", 1543);
```

In your case it is the `ExternalResource`. No need for the `Image` component.

Comment: Alas, I am using an IndexedContainer, so this doesn't really apply.

Comment: Well, it was just an example. Your `IndexedContainer` needs a column with values of type `Resource`, e.g. `ThemeResource` and then set the renderer like `grid.getColumn("yourColumn").setRenderer(new ImageRenderer())`.

Comment: I did all that. As I said, the same code works for Table. I've moved on and decided to go with Table instead. Perhaps the problem was that I declared the column as having `Image` type instead of `Resource`.

Comment: This answer is correct. What went wrong is that I tried setting the type of the property (column) as `ExternalResource`. Using `Resource.class` and passing the property a value of either `ExternalResource` or `ThemeResource` does the trick. Thank you.

Comment: You could mark it as answer than, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).